# How much can I turn before losing bonus movespeed?

Tags: league-of-legends

The new champion Aurelion Sol's ability Comet of Legend states he

> gains Escape Velocity while moving, up to 100. He also gains bonus
>   movement speed, based on how long he's been moving in the same
>   direction.

My question is how much can I turn and still be considered moving in the same direction? Is there a certain amount of degrees of rotation I may turn before losing all my bonus movespeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you break it down, the method of how the passive is working is based off of the physics formula of velocity + speed in a single direction. If you change direction even slightly, some of the velocity is lost. You completely change direction, the velocity in that direction is completely gone. [Check out this link for a better explained way.](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100310175444AAh2Iv7)

Your bonus movement speed is lost when you make a sharp turn; 45 degrees, 90 degrees etc. The best way to use the passive of Aurelion's travel is to always go directly straight. Even small turns can cause you to lose a bit of movement speed.

At best, you should practice with trying to hold onto as much escape velocity as possible while maintaining turns in the game to get a better angle at viewing and maintaining it. You might even get an edge on how to maintain it during skirmishes and team-fights, and that knowledge would be very advantageous for you and your team.

Answer (score 0):

It's around 20 degrees from your face. An L turn drops your speed quite fast.